# Need help understanding a proof (Bipartite Graph)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-explanation, bipartite-graphs

I was reading lecture notes of graphs(from MIT 6042) and am having trouble understanding this proof:

[image: Theorem 5.2.7]

I can't understand `Let d be value such that deg(l) >= x >= deg(r)`, what values do `d` and `x` represent here and why did we consider them?

And how did we arrive at `|N(S)|x >= |S|x`?

**Note:**

[image: Degree Constrained]

Comment: It might help if we knew the definition of a "bottleneck" and the statement of Theorem 5.2.5.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that $d$ should be replaced by $x$.  The consideration of $x$ must arise from the definition of "degree-constrained" - this is a term I am not familiar with.

Now for any subset $S$ of vertices in $L$, we have $d(v) \ge x$ for all $v \in S$.  Hence the number of edges leaving $S$ is $\sum_{v \in S} d(v) \ge x |S|$.

On the other hand, every such edge goes to $N(S)$ (by definition of what $N(S)$ is).  Every vertex in $v \in N(S)$ is in $R$, and hence receives $d(v) \le x$ edges.  Thus the number of edges from $S$ to $N(S)$ is at most $\sum_{v \in N(S)} d(v) \le x |N(S)|$ (note that vertices in $N(S)$ could also receive edges from vertices not in $S$, so even the sum of degrees is just an upper bound here).

Hence, by double-counting edges from $S$ to $N(S)$, we have
$$ |N(S)| x \ge e(S, N(S) ) \ge |S|x . $$

Comment: `x` has nothing to do with degree constrained. I edited the question and added its definition. I also can't understand the last line: `by double-counting edges from S to N(S)`, what does this mean? I am sorry if my questions are too basic.

Comment: Thanks for the definition.  $x$ does have to do with the graph being degree constrained: for example, take $x = \min_{v \in L} \text{deg}(v)$.  The degree constrained condition then guarantees $\text{deg}(l) \ge x \ge \text{deg}(r)$ for all $l \in L, r \in R$.

Comment: As for the "double-counting" line, we have a lower bound on the edges from $S$ to $N(S)$ by summing the degrees of the vertices in $S$.  We have an upper bound on the same quantity by summing the degrees of the vertices in $N(S)$.  Since these are bounding the same quantity, the upper bound must be bigger than the lower bound, which gives us the inequality we were looking for.